# Why chromium does not display objects while running load test for Truclient script but objects displayed perfectly fine while running script in local?

Tags: chromium, loadrunner, truclient

There are radio options those should be displayed when launching a web page in chromium. Radio options display correctly when running the Truclient script in local machine but they don't display/blank space when running the load test. This is failing my test. Has anyone faced this kind of issue?
Appreciate your help! Thanks.

Ran vugen script through command prompt(CLI) in LG. It worked fine. Errors only during the test.

Answer (score 0):

Tell us more about your script?

Do you have parameters, or do all of your users use the same data?

Does this happen with a single user running on a load generator, or just with multiple users running on a load generator?

How many users do you have on a single load generator when the error happens?

Does it happen with all scripts, or just one business script that is failing?